# toHaveFocus behaviour in jest-dom

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm having trouble understanding how `toHaveFocus()` works exactly. Here's my setup:

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import TextArea from './TextArea'


const Container = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  padding: ${props => props.theme.size};
`

const Title = styled(TextArea)`
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.sizeLarger};
  margin-left: ${props => props.theme.sizeSmall};
`

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  handleTitleChange = e => {
    this.props.onTitleChange(e.target.value)
  }

  handleTitleLostFocus = () => {
    this.props.onChangeComplete()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Title 
          value={this.props.item.title || ''}
          onChange={this.handleTitleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleTitleLostFocus}
        />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

**MyComponent.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {render, fireEvent, prettyDOM} from 'react-testing-library'

import MyComponent from '../MyComponent'


describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('handles title changes', () => {
    const title = 'title'
    const handleTitleChangeMock = jest.fn()
    const {getByText} = render(
      <MyComponent
        item={{
          title: title
        }}
        onTitleChange={handleTitleChangeMock}
        onChangeComplete={() => {}}
      />
    )
    const titleInput = getByText(title)
    console.log(prettyDOM(titleInput))
    fireEvent.click(getByText(title))
    expect(getByText(title)).toHaveFocus()
    fireEvent.change(getByText(title), {target: {value: title.slice(0, -1)}})
    expect(handleTitleChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(handleTitleChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(title.slice(0, -1))
  })
})
```

When I do this:

```
const titleInput = getByText(title)
console.log(prettyDOM(titleInput))
```

The console logs the following:

```
<textarea
    class="sc-htoDjs dLjZCT sc-bxivhb jdLTBU"
    style="height: 0px;"
  >
    title
  </textarea>
```

That `textarea` element is the one I am targeting. But then, when I do this:

```
fireEvent.click(titleInput)
expect(titleInput).toHaveFocus()
```

I get this error:

```
Received:
  <body><textarea style="min-height: 0 !important; max-height: none !important; height: 0px !important; visibility: hidden !important; overflow: hidden !important; position: absolute !important; z-index: -1000 !important; top: 0px !important; right: 0px;" /><div><div class="sc-bZQynM ePHCfO"><textarea class="sc-htoDjs dLjZCT sc-bxivhb jdLTBU" style="height: 0px;">title</textarea></div></div></body>

  at Object.it (src/__tests__/MyComponent.test.js:84:30)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I don't quite understand why when I'm trying to assert a `textarea` element `toHaveFocus()`, I'm receiving an error that references the entire DOM tree under `body`...

Comment: Can you post the whole test and the component?

Comment: I have added the full code for component and test.

Comment: Can you try to do `fireEvent.focus(titleInput)` rather than `click`?

Comment: I just tried it - same result...

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give focus using `titleInput.focus()` it works. I'm not sure why `fireEvent.focus` doesn't work.

You can see it working here https://codesandbox.io/s/y020r74rjj

Comment: Indeed, it seems to focus. On the other hand, I kind of wanted to test it correctly by simulating an actual user action as opposed to programmatically invoked `focus()`, which is why I'm trying `fireEvent.click()`.